# Error related to ICommand when running .NET 4.0 WPF application in Windows XP

Tags: wpf, mvvm, windows-xp

I have a WPF application that is targeted to the .NET 4.0 framework and uses the MVVM pattern with the MVVM Light toolkit. When I run this application on a Windows XP machine with the .NET 4.0 runtime installed, I get the following exception:

```
Could not load type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0 ...
```

I'm confused because the ICommand interface in .NET 4.0 is not in the System assembly but in PresentationCore.dll. And in any case the XP machine should have all of the 4.0 assemblies at its disposal. Does anyone know how to resolve this exception?

Comment: Are you running the application inside or outside Visual Studio?

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Comment: @Bernard Outside Visual Studio. The XP machine has no dev tools installed. But I have found a solution now--see my response.

Comment: @Will I have found a solution, but I had not heard of this tool before and it seems useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue went away after I ran Windows update and selected all of the optional updates related to .NET 4.0. So maybe it was just something that was not completely up-to-date in the framework.